# How to draw samples from two variables from population

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataset that female students have than male. I need analyze which gender perform better in their test. Because their number not equal, I need to draw sample which equal.

```
female=df.sample (df.query ("gender=='female'")=200)
male=df.sample (df.query ("gender=='male'")=200)
```

Is this correct code ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Among other things, you have a syntax error. Assuming you want 200 samples from each population, try this:

```
female = df[df['gender']=='female'].sample(200)
male   = df[df['gender']==  'male'].sample(200)
```

Comment: it doesn't work.ValueError: a must be greater than 0

Comment: i copied n paste your code. 'a' is something else. not from your code. Thanks anyway